# В БД кириллица записывается как "?????"

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Сделал регистрацию на сайте asp.net MVC 5, с использованием EF. При добавлении строки в таблицу, поле с кириллицей записывается как "?????".

Столбец типа `NVARCHAR(100)`, так что проблема не в БД. На `HTML-странице` использую `UTF-8` кодировку, как и файл этого контроллера и самой страницы. Выводит из БД русский текст тоже без проблем.

Может, проблема в самом сервере? Или что-то добавить в `Web.config`?
Пробовал добавлять в `connectionStrings` параметр `charset=utf8` в разные места, ловил исключения:

- `The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.`
- `Keyword not supported: 'charset'.`

Установлена английская Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (v.14.0.25420.01 Update 3). В настройках проекта: `Neutral Language: Russian (Russia)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код страницы:

```
@model HotelSystem.hs_users

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HotelSystem - Регистрация</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/register_form.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Html.Partial("_Header")
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div id="msform">
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Создание аккаунта</h2>

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Логин" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Email" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Пароль" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.confirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Подтверждение пароля" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fullname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Полное имя" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fullname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Регистрация" class="submit action-button" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</body>
</html>
```

Код контроллера:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HotelSystem.Controllers
{
    public class userController : Controller
    {
        HotelSystemDatabaseEntities1 db = new HotelSystemDatabaseEntities1();

        ...

        public ActionResult register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult register(hs_users U)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                U.role = 1;
                U.time = DateTime.Now;
                db.hs_users.Add(U);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                U = null;
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }
            return View(U);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string username)
        {
            int user = 0;
            try
            {
                user = db.hs_users.Count(u => u.username == username);
            }
            catch { }

            if (user == 0)
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult doesEmailAddressExist(string email)
        {
            int user = 0;
            try
            {
                user = db.hs_users.Count(u => u.email == email);
            }
            catch { }

            if (user == 0)
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код модели:

```
namespace HotelSystem
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public partial class hs_users
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Заполните поле")]
        [Remote("doesUserNameExist", "user", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Такой логин уже зарегистрирован")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{2,49}$", ErrorMessage = "Некорректный логин")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Заполните поле")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Пароль должен быть от {2} до {1} символов", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Заполните поле")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "Введенные пароли не совпадают")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string confirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Заполните поле")]
        public string fullname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Заполните поле")]
        [Remote("doesEmailAddressExist", "user", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Такой Email уже зарегистрирован")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Введите корректный Email")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        public System.DateTime time { get; set; }

        public int role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Connection string из файла `Web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
        name="HotelSystemDatabaseEntities1"
        connectionString="
            metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
            provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
            provider connection string=&quot;
            data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
            attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\HotelSystemDatabase.mdf;
            integrated security=True;
            multipleactiveresultsets=True;
            application name=EntityFramework&quot;"
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889438/entity-framework-c-sharp-insert-data-russian-encoding-problems) похожий случай (mysql). Советуют добавить `charset=utf8` в строку подключения.

Comment: Не получилось добавить (у меня не mysql). К посту добавил код `connectionStrings` и вверху исключения которые возникают. Погуглив, ничего не нашёл.

Comment: А почему вы до сих пор используете старый EF, а не EF Code First?

Comment: Старый? В проекте установлен `EntityFramework 6.1.3`, новее некуда. Почему не `Code First`? Потому что `Database First` мне проще. Да что от этого изменится?

Comment: @BabaYaga какой collation задан у поля/у таблицы/у базы?

Comment: @PashaPash не уверен, что правильно посмотрел, но на запрос `SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));` выдало `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: @BabaYaga это глобальная настройка уровня сервера. посмотрите collation в свойствах базы, в свойствах таблицы и в свойствах колонки - вдруг где-то вписан нестандартный

Comment: @BabaYaga ок, давайте с другой стороны попробуем - проверьте свойство проблемного поля в маппинге и убедитесь что на нем стоит отметка Unicode - true - вот примерно так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq6rL.jpg

Comment: @PashaPash стоит false.

Comment: @BabaYaga ну вот, поменяйте на true - если поможет - я запощу как ответ

Comment: @PashaPash не помогло

Comment: @BabaYaga ок, тогда берите исходники EF и дебагайте до самого вызова SQL, смотрите какой тип у параметра, который в котором передается строчка - может быть там теряется unicode. Или по крайней мере возьмите sql профайлер и посмотрите, что передается в запросе и в какой кодировке.

Comment: @BabaYaga я к тому, что того кода, который приведен в ответе, недостаточно для воспроизведения проблемы. разметка не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме, код контроллера - тоже. Попробуйте собрать минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы (который можно будет скопировать локально и запустить!) - этого требуют правила. Иначе отвечающие будут гадать (вот как я гадаю выше) - а вдруг вы не там unicode поставили? а вдруг у вас не пересобрался проект? а вдруг что-то еще?

Comment: @PashaPash Ну вот проект - https://yadi.sk/d/FSrXTyiU32NsnB

Comment: @BabaYaga я имел ввиду не выложить проект куда-то, а самому попытаться построить [минимальный пример для вопроизведения проблемы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). и поместить его прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash Сделал такой, там всё работает -_- Не знаю, что багнулось в изначальном проекте... Я просто пересоздам и скопирую весь остальной код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF кэширует модель базы в момент рефреша. У вас в Model1.edmx/edmx:StorageModels написано следующее:

```
<Property Name="fullname" Type="varchar" MaxLength="100" Nullable="false" />
```

И это заставляет EF криво мапить данные.

Рефреш модели на основе базы решает проблему.

Comment: @BabaYaga ок, смотрите - если сделать refresh модели на основе базы - все работает нормально. Значит проблема где-то в модели.

Comment: @BabaYaga все, нашел

Comment: @BabaYaga подправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если в запросе задается юникодная константа, то перед ней нужно обязательно ставить символ N. Чтобы показать разницу, достаточно простого запроса:

SELECT '致死罪 ANSI', N'致死罪 UNICODE'

---

??? ANSI   致死罪 UNICODE
Если не указывать N перед константой, то SQL Server будет пытаться искать подходящий символ в ANSI кодировке. Если не найдет, то подставит знак вопроса.

Comment: Это тут причём? Тут c SQL кодом работает только EF. А он уже сам разберётся, где ставить N, а где не надо